# QString New Line

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtcore

I want to add a new line to my `QString`. I tried to use `\n`, but I am receiving an error of "Expected Expression". An example of my code can  be found below:

```
if (ui->lineEdit_Company_Name->text().isEmpty())
    ErrorLog = ErrorLog + "Company Name is empty", \r\n;
if(ui->lineEdit_Company_Owner->text().isEmpty())
    ErrorLog = ErrorLog + "Company Owner is empty", \r\n;
```

Comment: In Qt 5.6, you need `\n` or `\r\n` inside the actual quotation marks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use [operator+](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qstring.html#operator-2b-20), [push_back](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qstring.html#push_back), [append](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qstring.html#append) or some other means for appending when using `std::string`, `QString` and the like. Comma (',') is not a concatenation character. Therefore, write this:

```
if (ui->lineEdit_Company_Name->text().isEmpty())
    ErrorLog = ErrorLog + "Company Name is empty\n";
if(ui->lineEdit_Company_Owner->text().isEmpty())
    ErrorLog = ErrorLog + "Company Owner is empty\n";
```

Please also note that `\n` is enough in this context to figure out the platform dependent line end for files, GUI controls and the like if needed. Qt will go through the regular standard means, APIs or if needed, it will solve it on its own.

To be fair, [you could simplify it even further](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qstring.html#operator-2b-eq):

```
if (ui->lineEdit_Company_Name->text().isEmpty())
    ErrorLog += "Company Name is empty\n";
    // or ErrorLog.append("Company Name is empty\n");
    // or ErrorLog.push_back("Company Name is empty\n");
if(ui->lineEdit_Company_Owner->text().isEmpty())
    ErrorLog += "Company Owner is empty\n";
    // or ErrorLog.append("Company Owner is empty\n");
    // or ErrorLog.push_back("Company Owner is empty\n");
```

Practically speaking, when you use constant string, it is worth considering the use of [QStringLiteral](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qstring.html#QStringLiteral) as it builds the string compilation-time if the compiler supports the corresponding C++11 feature.

Answer (score 5):

I would concur with [lpapp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2682142/lpapp) that you should simply incorporate the `'\n'` into the string literal you are appending. So:

```
if (ui->lineEdit_Company_Name->text().isEmpty()){
    ErrorLog += "Company Name is empty\n";
}
if(ui->lineEdit_Company_Owner->text().isEmpty()){
    ErrorLog += "Company Owner is empty\n";
}
```

But I'd like to also mention that the not just Qt, but C++ in general translates, `'\n'` to the correct line ending for your platform. See this link for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `endl` as follow:

```
ErrorLog += "Company Name is empty" + endl;
```